# Rails 4: JQuery mobile overlapping with Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

Ever since I have installed JQuery mobile on my Rails 4 application, every view is now formatted by JQuery mobile. I would like to only apply JQuery mobile to one view and not the entire application. At this point Foundation is overlapping with JQuery mobile's formatting. Some textboxes are even being rendered twice. Also when validation of the textboxes fails, the page renders with another set of textboxes and Signup buttons embedded within the old ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I simply ended up uninstalling the jquery mobile gem and did a generic install. This seems to have worked. Still don't know exactly what happened.